# optimizing a really long code with a lot of JOINS on Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, query-tuning

I need help with a really long existing code that runs on Amazon Redshift. It is returning a WLM timeout therefore I need to optimize or improve it somehow so it won't get the WLM anymore.

Here is the code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CsgFNisb77qWc3t5KUVQkVGA4iPtk5ER/view?usp=sharing

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than posting a link, please include the code in the question.

Comment: I tried that but it won't allow me to.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Laurenz. I hope you still can shed some light on my problem.